# Поиск всех путей графа и информацию о них

Tags: java, графы

Граф задан набором отношений

```
private final SimpleStringProperty sender;
    private final SimpleStringProperty LQI;
    private final SimpleStringProperty neighbor;
```

(таблица ID вершины, вес ребра, ID вершины), причем есть как отношения A->B, так и B->A (т.к. значения ребер разные) Как можно вывести все возможные пути в тектовое поле.

Comment: А как связаны графы и JavaFX, чет немного не понял (

Comment: Данные в таблицу графа через `javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;` добавляются